# Getting the row-position when using order by

Tags: mysql

I'm looking to get the row number of a horse in order by so i can see where it lies within the order.

I have used the following code

```
SELECT `odds`, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tom_cards` WHERE `Racetime` = "14:30" Order By `Odds`) AS `position`, `Horse` FROM `tom_cards` WHERE `Racetime` = "14:30"
```

put this creates all the positions as 8

```
> odds  position    Horse
> 100.00    8   Central School
> 1.25  8   Coologue
> 1.10  8   Ma du Fou
> 33.00 8   Quintano
> 66.00 8   The Mobb
> 12.00 8   The Western Force
> 22.00 8   Youngdocgallagher
> 8.00  8   Tara Mac
```

I would like it to be in order of Odds from lowest to highest like below:

```
odds    position    Horse
100.00  8   Central School
1.25    2   Coologue
1.10    1   Ma du Fou
33.00   6   Quintano
66.00   7   The Mobb
12.00   4   The Western Force
22.00   5   Youngdocgallagher
8.00    3   Tara Mac
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: `ORDER BY Odss DESC`?

Comment: Thats obvious. **`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tom_cards` WHERE `Racetime` = "14:30" Order By `Odds`** returns the total number of records with racetime = 14:30 which is fixed for this scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do what you want with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT `odds`,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM `tom_cards` tc2
        WHERE tc2.Racetime = tc.RaceTime and tc2.Odds <= tc.Odds
      ) AS `position`, `Horse`
FROM `tom_cards` tc
WHERE `Racetime` = '14:30';
```

I am guessing that if you have duplicate odds, then you want them to have the same "position".  If so, you want the equivalent of a `rank()` (which is the ANSI standard function for this operation but MySQL does not support it):

```
SELECT `odds`,
       (SELECT 1 + COUNT(*)
        FROM `tom_cards` tc2
        WHERE tc2.Racetime = tc.RaceTime and tc2.Odds < tc.Odds
      ) AS `position`, `Horse`
FROM `tom_cards` tc
WHERE `Racetime` = '14:30';
```

Answer (score 1):

Since select statement returns same value regardless of row, you should not use it there to display position. To display position try this

```
SET @position:=0;
SELECT `odds`, @position:=@position+1 AS `position`, `Horse` FROM `tom_cards` WHERE `Racetime` = "14:30" ORDER BY `odds`;
```

**[Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5200/1)**

Answer (score 0):

You can Try This.

```
SELECT `odds` , (@row:=@row+1) AS `POSITION`, `Horse` FROM `tom_cards`,(SELECT @row := 0)r WHERE `Racetime` = "14:30" ORDER BY `odds`;
```

Comment: it should be `ORDER BY ` and not `OREDER BY `

Comment: It was a typo. Thanks @krishna :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

You can modify your query as follows:

```
SELECT `odds`, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tom_cards` WHERE `Racetime` = t2.`Racetime` and `odds` <= t2.`odds`) AS `position`, `Horse` FROM `tom_cards` as t2 WHERE `Racetime` = "14:30"
```

But you need to be careful here, that if multiple records have the same racetime (e.g. 14:30), then each will have the same position value. So it may not be exactly the same as the position in the Order By.

Also, because of the subquery this query will not perform well on large data sets.

Solution 2:

Use a variable as others already recommended.

Problem is, that the evaluation order of expressions in selects is not determined, so you need to be careful if you have further plans with the position info. E.g. refer to [here](https://books.google.be/books?id=IagfgRiKWd4C&pg=PA253&lpg=PA253&dq=select+%22@rownum%22+mysql+problem&source=bl&ots=wZb0p_PzGg&sig=4YkT_YB5rQBKTN0qV4QPfGok-v4&hl=hu&sa=X&ei=XYKuVPCvAqf17AaivYGYCw&ved=0CFIQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=select%20%22%40rownum%22%20mysql%20problem&f=false) or [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html)

Solution 3:

Your question is tagged as a php question, so you can also just query the result set and calculate the position in php. This seems to be most effective.

Comment: @krishna Thanks for the correction. I did not want to say that such a solution was not working, I just wanted to point out that OP needs to be careful when using variables. I made it more clear.